# Is it possible to feed a model name into a Future as a variable or use a callback in a Future in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

### Background

I understand the concept of callbacks from JS.  Being on day #5 of flutter I don't really understand the interplay with callbacks at all in dart/flutter.

So please bear with me

### What I'm trying to accomplish

I'm trying to build a single set of reusable code that can communicate from my app to a JSON site to make various different JSON requests via the same exact code base

### What I have right now

I have a Future call which successfully polls a site for JSON data and sends it off for parsing by using a specific model.

```
          Future<Result> getJSONfromTheSite(String thecall) async {
            try {
              //2
              final response = await client.request(requestType: RequestType.GET,
                  path: thecall).timeout(const Duration(seconds: 8));
              if (response.statusCode == 200) {
                //3
                return Result<MyModel>.success(MyModel.fromRawJson(response.body));
              } else {
                return Result.error(title:"Error",msg:"Status code not 200", errorcode:1);
              }
            } catch (error) {
                 (...)
            }
          }
```

I'm making the request via my UI page like this:

```
FutureBuilder(
                future: _apiResponse.getJSONfromTheSite('latestnews'),
                builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<Result> snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.data is SuccessState) { ...
```

Using the variable `thecall` which I feed in from the FutureBuilder on my various UI pages I can successfully change which http JSON request is being made to poll for different data.

### What I'm stuck on

Where I'm stuck is that while I can successfully vary the request to change what data I'm polling for, I can't do anything with the result because my current code always wants to use `MyModel` to parse the JSON.

```
return Result<MyModel>.success(MyModel.fromRawJson(response.body));
```

#### The question

I essentially need to be able to switch the Model being used against this JSON data depending on what UI page is making the request, rather then hardcoding 10 versions of the same code.

I was thinking of feeding in the name of the model I want to use for that specific call via the FutureBuilder call.  For example something like `future: _apiResponse.getJSONfromTheSite('latestnews', MyModel2),` but that didn't work at all.
Alternatively I was thinking of having the entire `return Result<MyModel>.success(MyModel2.fromRawJson(response.body));` sent in as a callback.

The concept of callback makes sense from my JS days, but I'm not sure if I'm correctly applying the concept here.  So if I'm going about this the wrong way I'm all ears to a more elegant solution.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You could simply pass as a callback the constructor you want to use and make your method `getJSONfromTheSite` dynamically typed. The only issue is that you won't be able to define `fromRawJson` as a factory constructor but instead as a static method returning an instance of your object.

### Code Sample

```dart
// Your method fromRawJson should be implemented like this
class MyModel {
  // ...

  static MyModel fromRawJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
      MyModel(/* your parameters */);
}

/// T is the dynamic type which you will use to define if it is
/// MyModel or any other class.
Future<Result<T>> getJSONfromTheSite<T>(
  String thecall,
  T Function(Map<String, dynamic>) jsonFactory,
) async {
  try {
    // ...

    return Result<T>.success(jsonFactory(response));
  } catch (error) {
    // ...
  }
}

// Then you can call your method like this
await getJSONfromTheSite<MyModel>('latestnews', MyModel.fromRawJson);

// For another class such as MyModel2 it would be like this
await getJSONfromTheSite<MyModel2>('', MyModel2.fromRawJson);
```

[Try the full code on DartPad](https://dartpad.dev/5932ba2e3763e482d454ea7479aea1a6?null_safety=true)